# VOIP to Sim possible?

Tags: iphone, voip, sim-card

Is it possible to get a VOIP number that I already have, and transfer that void into a SIM card, so I can use it as a normal number?

Doubt it helps but I’m on an iPhone wanting to this..

Comment: I flagged this question as having nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff im sorry, I was told that this was a place to go for a question like this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your VOIP provider forwarding incoming calls to your SIM card number or in better cases (in case of PSTN phone number) you can request to your SIM provider a portability from your VoIP provider to your SIM provider (this request flow is very important)